# CiviDiscount - Automatic discounts for number of attendees

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

I have a site that's using CiviDiscount and the question has come up if advanced filters for automatic discounts can be configured based on number of attendees being registered for an event, irrespective of membership type/status or contact type, etc.

Example

- Single ticket @ £75
- 10 tickets @ £60/ticket

So once 10 participants added, I'd like an automatic discount (let's say 20%) applied.

I want to the extra participants registered so a price set won't work. I know there's potential workarounds in terms of using a price set and using custom fields etc. but thought it's worth asking the question.

Any guidance hugely appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

this can be achieved using an event price set. If you create a price set you can create a ticket option which takes up multiple "seats" at the event. You can create a 10 person ticket option and then set the price of that option.

Note however in that approach you cannot require that all 10 attendees submit separate registration details and you can only collect the details from the first participant who is buying the 10 person ticket.

Best